# Liquibase LoadData setting foreignkey reference with valuecomputed doesnt work

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

Importing this foreignkey doesnt work with valueComputing. Anyone got an idea how to set this up properly? I already searched on google but i didnt find anything. I also asked chatgpt but its just sending me the same answer over and over again saying it should be working.

So i am setting up liquibase for my project. I have 2 tables. Each of them got a systemId which is just a value of 6 characters.

```
<changeSet id="create_tb_states" author="fas">
    <createTable tableName="tb_states">
        <column name="autoid" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" unique="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="systemId" type="VARCHAR(6)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="displayName" type="VARCHAR(64)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

And

```
<changeSet id="create_tb_districts" author="fas">
    <createTable tableName="tb_districts">
        <column name="autoid" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" unique="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="systemId" type="VARCHAR(6)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="displayName" type="VARCHAR(64)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="state_ref" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_districts_states" referencedTableName="tb_states" referencedColumnNames="autoid" unique="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

So i want to load basedata from a csv file. At first the tb_states csv is loaded in. Thats perfectly working. But when i want to load the districts csv it needs to set the state_ref.
So i tried this

```
<changeSet id="insert districts basedata" author="fas">
    <loadData
            file="db/changelog/baseData/tb_districts.csv"
            separator=","
            tableName="tb_districts">
        <column name="state_ref" type="NUMERIC" defaultValueComputed="(SELECT autoid FROM tb_states WHERE systemId = state)"/>
        <column name="systemId" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="displayName" type="STRING"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

On this approach i get this error message FEHLER: Spalte »state« von Relation »tb_districts« existiert nicht
Position: 27. (sorry for german)

First 3 lines of my csv btw

```
state,systemId,displayName
'NORWES',AACHEN,Städteregion Aachen
'NORWES',BIEELD,Kreisfreie Stadt Bielefeld
'NORWES',BOCHUM,Kreisfreie Stadt Bochum
```

And if i add

```
<column name="state" type="STRING"/>
```

(the column state is the systemId of the tb_states item)
im getting this error

FEHLER: NULL-Wert in Spalte »state_ref« verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
Detail: Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (6, AACHEN, Städteregion Aachen, null).